# `BufferReader` not showing the console input (typed) until ENTER is pressed (only in Windows & Mac, works in Linux)

Tags: java, windows, input, bufferedreader

I wanted to capture user input in two ways, one without timeout (waiting till life) another within some time period (if time exceeds/timeout it should be considered `null` or no input and move ahead). So I had this code.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Type Something (timeout 5 Sec)");

        /* Read input within 5 Sec or done, whichever happens first*/
        String inputTimeOut = executeInTime(Main::readInput, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("TimeOut Inupt Given: " + inputTimeOut);

        System.out.println("Type Something");
        /* Read Input without time restriction */
        String input = readInput();
        System.out.println("Inupt Given: " + input);
    }

    public static String executeInTime(Callable<String> call, long wait, TimeUnit unit) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<String> task = executorService.submit(call);
        String input = null;
        try {
            input = task.get(wait, unit);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            task.cancel(true);
        } finally {
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
        return input;
    }

    public static String readInput() {
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            while (!buffer.ready()) {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
            String input = buffer.readLine();
            return input;
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

It worked fine in Linux. Also in Wondows, the end behaviour is same, but there is a small problem.
In windows/Mac, I can't see what I've typed so far until I press enter. In Linux (Ubuntu) it appears as soon as I type.

Any idea why it's behaving differently in windows? And any other solution is also welcomed, as far as it allows the reading operation to be interruptible/killable and common (like my `readInput()`).

Update:

If I comment this

```
while (!buffer.ready()) {
    Thread.sleep(5);
}
```

it shows while typing but does not end the execution after timeout.

(I can't use `System.exit` on timeout, sorry.)

Comment: I am really surprised that this works on any of the platforms ... when System.in is reading from a console device.  Console devices (ttys) and virtual consoles on UNIX / Linux / BSD do line buffering / editing by default.

Comment: @StephenC it works on linux (ubuntu 20.04 to be more precise). In Mac and Windows it is not behaving the same way.

Comment: Edited the code so that you can copy-paste the whole snippet and try in Linux at least. Even I'm confused about the different behavior.